# XAML Hot Reload is disabled because it requires a newer version of Xamarin.Forms after I updated

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

So I updated my Xamarin.Forms version to 4.4.0.991477, updated it for all project and their PackageReferences, updated/deleted a few NuGet packages to get rid of old references (For example CarouselView is built into Xamarin.Forms 4.0+ so I don't need to NuGet package anymore) but whenever I relaod my project, I still get the

```
XAML Hot Reload is disabled because it requires Xamarin.Forms 4.1.0.581479 or newer
```

Then prompts me to update XF pacakges. Well I  thought I already did update forms using the steps I mentioned, am I missing something? Is there a way to double check that Xamarin.Forms actually did get updated?

Comment: I'm having the same problem having upgraded to xamarin.forms 5.0.0.2012 and afterwards (because of too many incompatibilities) downgraded to a version below. Did you ever solve your problem, if so please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

The three steps works well for me. You could have a try.

1. Check the version of your Visual Studio. It required 16.4 or greater.
2. Check the Version of your Xamarin.forms. Uninstall and reinstall it. Delete the obj and bin folder to clean and rebuild the project.
3. On Windows, XAML Hot Reload can be enabled by checking the Enable Xamarin Hot Reload checkbox at Tools > Options > Xamarin > Hot Reload.